# Possible to specify environment variables common to multiple Tasks somewhere central?

Tags: bamboo

I have a Job that consists of a number of Tasks which each require the same environment variables (e.g. `ANDROID_HOME`, `JAVA_HOME`). Currently, I've copy-pasted these environment variables in the `Environment variables` input field of each of the Tasks. I'd prefer it if I was able to specify Environment variables that are common to multiple Tasks somewhere central in the Job or Stage or Plan setup. Is this possible?

I thought the `Plan Configuration > Miscellaneous > Environment variables` input field might do it but alas the environment variables entered here are not picked up by the Tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create plan or global variable Plan Configuration > Variables

[image: Define plan variable]

Then use defined variable at your task:

[image: Use plan variable at task's Environment variables field]

Run build and see results

[image: build results]

Comment: Excellent. That worked. I added a plan-wide variable named `environment` which has as its value the space-delimited list of all my environment variables and then I set the `Environment variables` input field in each of my Tasks to `${bamboo.environment}`. Seems like a bit of a workaround but it works so hey-ho. Thanks for your help!